# Download TFS 2015 Build Agent without TFS 2015 install

Tags: xaml, continuous-integration, tfs-2015

We currently use TFS 2013 with a suite of XAML builds, there are a few hundred projects here, each with an average of six build definitions each.

We're wanting to upgrade to TFS 2017 (2018 doesn't support XAML) but need to be able to support the XAML builds until they're all migrated.

According to MS, we can setup a TFS 2017 box, a build server with a 2017 build agent on it and a separate build server with a 2015 build agent on it which TFS can use to run the XAML builds.

My problem is... where to get the 2015 build agent installer from.  Normally you ask TFS for the build agent installer, but we don't have a TFS 2015 installation.

Am I going to have to setup a TFS 2015 VM just so I can click one lousy link and download one installer.  I've searched around but can't find any other place to get the damned thing from.

Anyone got a link to an MS page?

Answer (score 1):

You could download the latest build agent from the link below:
[Download Latest Agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases) , which will download the "vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.xxx.x.zip" file for you. Currently I believe that both TFS 2015 and TFS 2017 are downloading the same latest agent as mentioned above.

If you need a specific version of the agent you could take a look at the git hub for [the specific Releases of the VSTS agents](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases)

Comment: A colleague is working at a site where they still have a 2015 installation so he managed to putll a copy from his TFS for me.  I'm not sure if you are correct about 2015 and 2017 agents being the same though, the 2017 version is about 84Mb and the 2015 is under 12Gb.  Thanks for the link though, useful to know.

Comment: Sure, that was some time ago, when I have simultaneously both TFS 2015 and TFS 2017, so now it could be a bit different in term of size. I believe that you mean under 12MB instead for TFS 2015? :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct actually. The TFS 2015 and TFS 2017 build agents are different. I was referring to downloading build agents on-prem for either VSTS account, or from a TFS 2017 on-prem installation, that were targeting similar version of the vsts agent. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries mate, I appreciate the info. nonetheless.  In the end it turned out that it was easier to install a full (but minimal) TFS2015 on the build server and just use the Controller and Build Agent.  We do now have the whole 2017->2015->2013 suite up and working though. Sweet!